# Setting an animation to happen only at launch?

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, iboutlet, viewdidappear

I have a question I hope you guys will be able to help me out with. So pretty much I have a basic animation and I want it to only occur when the app launches and not when I actually travel back to the page once I'm in the app, cause right now I have it in the viewWillAppear method. Below is my code for the animation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also as you may tell when looking at my code, Im trying to fade the image in, if you know a better way to do so can you please show me as well? But that works fine.

My .m:

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"
@interface HomeViewController ()
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *logo;
@end
@implementation HomeViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[self logo]setAlpha:0];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
    [[self logo]setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: How about placing it in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Or use `dispatch_once`. Or have some `BOOL` property (or `static`) that you set once you do the animation, and only do that animation again according to the value of that `BOOL` property.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/)?

You could do something like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (![userDefaults boolForKey:@"didPlayAnimation"])
{        
    [[self logo]setAlpha:0];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
         [[self logo]setAlpha:1];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"didPlayAnimation"];
    }]
}
```

I'd suggest you to use a block-based animation as you see in the code above, as the begin/commit animation method you are using is discouraged on iOS 4.0 and later (see [UIView class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)).

As you want to perform every time the app is launched, set that BOOL to NO when the app terminates. You can do this in the method

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

of your app delegate, i.e. the class that implements the UIApplicationDelegate protocol.